# Highcharts Export with fontSize in em

Tags: highcharts, phantomjs

I have a highchart in which I have used em values for all the font sizes to allow for changes to make the chart more flexible to changes in CSS on the page.  The chart works fine, but when I export it, the fonts are much larger than they appear on the page.  I am assuming this is because there is a base font size in the export process that is larger than the base font size I have on the page.

Is there a way to set the base font size for the chart on export so that the font sizes with ems appear the same size when they are exported?

Comment: If you are using Highcharts exporting server, all you can do is to set everywhere for [chartOptions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.chartOptions) fontSize in pt/px and set width/height. Or setup your own exporting server..

Comment: I am using my own local exporting server using the phantomjs export.  Is there a way to set the base font size on my own exporting server?